# ActionBar Tab indicator getting stuck between tabs

Tags: android, tabs

I have implemented ActionBar tabs following this guide: [github](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-SlidingTabLayout). However I have a problem with the tab indicator getting stuck between the 2nd and 3rd tab. Like there is 4 tabs, but only 3 shown. Looks like this:

[image: tabs]

It's only when I slide from the 3rd tab to the 2nd. It just stays there, and if i slide left again, it goes to the 2nd tab. So it basically just feels like there is 4 tabs.

```
My FragmentPagerAdapter Class looks like this

    public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private static Context context;
    private String tabTitles[];

    public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
        this.context = context;
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        tabTitles = new String[] { resources.getString(R.string.recent),
            resources.getString(R.string.popular),
            resources.getString(R.string.my) };
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new RecentFragment();

        case 1:
            return new PopularFragment();

        case 2:
            return new MyFragment();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

    public static class RecentFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

        ListView listView;
        List<RowItem> rowItems;

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, container, false);
            String[] titles = { "titleA", "titleB", "titleC" };
            String[] descriptions = { "a", "b", "c" };
            Integer[] images = { R.drawable.christoffer, R.drawable.frede, R.drawable.sofie };

            rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
            for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
                RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], descriptions[i]);
                rowItems.add(item);
            }

            listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
            CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(context,
                    R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }

    public static class PopularFragment extends Fragment {

    }

    public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    }

}
```

My SlidingTabLayout and SlidingTabStrip classes looks excatly like the one in the guide. And in the MainActivity I have added this code to implement the tabs:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this));

// Give the SlidingTabLayout the ViewPager
SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
// Center the tabs in the layout
slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
// Customize tab color
slidingTabLayout
        .setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return Color.RED;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Try `return new Fragment();` instead of `return null;` in your `getItem()` method - Just a wild guess!

Comment: If you comment line slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true); than what happens?

Comment: I `return new Fragment()` at first in develop-time as Skynet guessed, and came up with the same issue, then I found this question. Finally it saves me that `return` a non-null view in `onCreateView`. That means if I continued coding then the bug will disappear, but I wasted lots of time on it…

Answer (score 0):

Please load fragment XML into all tabs through java file and it will solve..